# .NET 5 WindowsService with ASP.NET Core and BackgroundService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services, .net-5

I'm new here and new to .NET 5, and I'm really stuck with my problem.
I have an .NET 5 application that should be executed as a Windows Service and that has an ASP.NET Core (Kestrel?) REST service and some BackgroundService in it.
The BackgroundService is some sort of polling service to some server and the REST service is intended for retrieving the processed polling result to some web application.

It is all working without problems when started from command line, but when deployed and started as a Windows Service, it will be ended unexpectedly after just a few seconds.

The problem arises only, if the ASP.NET Core REST service is activated, if my BackgroundService is executed alone, it is also working as Windows Service.
The ASP.NET Core REST service (without BackgroundService) alone is also not working as Windows Service - so maybe just the ASP.NET Core / Windows Service startup is not implemented correctly.

This is what i do:

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
        {
            await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
            return 0;
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(directoryName)
                .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(directoryName, "appsettings.json"), false, true)
                .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(directoryName, "appsettings.custom.json"), true, true)
                .AddCommandLine(args)
                .Build();

            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseUrls(baseUrl);
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel();
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .UseWindowsService(options => options.ServiceName = "MyService");
            
        }
    }
```

My startup code:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;          
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            try
            {
                services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>(provider =>
                    new MyBackgroundService(loggerForMyBackgroundService, configuration))
                        .Configure<EventLogSettings>(config =>
                        {
                            config.LogName = "MyService";
                            config.SourceName = "MyService";
                        });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError($"Error during startup: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }

            services.AddCors();
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            
            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
                .AllowCredentials());
            app.UseAuthorization();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if there is something missing. Or is it just a matter of putting everything into the right order?
Is it possible to host a BackgroundService AND an ASP.NET Core REST service in ONE single Windows Service?

Thank you very much for your help.

Best regards,
Carsten

Comment: You can use the event viewer on the server to see if there are any messages.  A service has limited access to the resources on the machine.  Services are normally started by default using a System account with no Environmental variables.  If your app is using the environment than it will fail.  One solution is to create a Service account with an environment.  Than start the service using the service account.

Comment: string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

That part seems to work even if it is started as Windows Service

Comment: In the EventViewer there's only an entry that the service was ended unexpectedly. Event id 7034.

Comment: indeed it has something to do with the environment. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the problem.
Starting the Windows Server with Debugger.Launch() and enabling all Exceptions in Visual Studio finally led to an exception message:

Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.

So yes, it has something to do with the environment - thank you @jdweng!
The Windows Service does not seem to be able to get to the web development default certificate, so i will use an own dedicated certificate for my service.

It is a good idea to wrap the main method in a try catch block with an output to the Event Log to see such errors like so:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    
    try
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            SerilogLoggingBuilderExtensions.AddSerilog(
                 builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning)
                        .AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning)
                        .AddFilter("MyNamespace", LogLevel.Debug)
                        .AddEventLog()
                        .AddConsole());
        });
        ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(typeof(Program)); 
        logger.LogError(e.Message);
        return -1;
    }
}
```